# DataTables Editor - How to allow updating password field in inline editing using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery-datatables-editor

In my **DataTables Editor** project, I am trying to update password using inline editing method, but it does allow not allow me to update the password. I mean when I select a password field it automatically submitted, without allow me to do the change.

Here is a clip of my problem: [Inline Password editing problem](https://bytesoft.tinytake.com/tt/MzY3NjkzMV8xMTE2MDAwMQ)

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?